# in the lambda calculus with products and sums is $f : [n] \to [n]$ $\beta\eta$ equivalent to $f^{n!}$?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

$\eta$-reduction is often described as arising from the desire for functions which are point-wise equal to be syntactically equal. In a simply typed calculus with products it is sufficient, but when sums are involved I fail to see how to reduce point-wise equal functions to a common term.

For example, it is easy to verify that any function $f: (1+1) \to (1+1)$ is point-wise equal to $\lambda x.f(fx)$, or more generally $f$ is point-wise equal to $f^{n!}$ when $f: A \to A$ and $A$ has exactly $n$ inhabitants.  Is it possible to reduce $f^{n!}$ to $f$?  If not, is there an extension of the simply typed calculus which allows this reduction?

Comment: What does "pointwise equal" mean, *precisely*?

Comment: two functions $f, g:A \to A$ are point-wise equal if for any $a:A$, $f(a) =_{\beta\eta} g(a)$.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a sufficient explanation for type theory. What is $a$ here? Closed term? A term in a context?

Comment: I would be happy to know a solution for closed terms.  How about: two closed terms $f, g:A \to A$ are point-wise equal if for all closed terms $a:A, f(a) =_{\beta\eta} g(a)$?

Comment: Nope, you can't get that.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think so.  Do you know of any weakening of the conditions which would allow it?  Alternatively, is there a stronger notion of reduction which reduces point-wise equal functions to a common term (and doesn't reduce non point-wise functions to a common term)?

Comment: Function extensionality, but that's in dependent type theory with identity types.